# If $P(G)=\{f\in L_1(G): f\geq 0, \int f d\lambda(x)=1\}$ Prove $\overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^*$ = $\mathfrak{M}(G)$

Tags: limits-and-convergence, amenability

Let  $\mathfrak{M}(G)$ be the set of all means on $L_\infty (G)$

> If $P(G)=\{f\in L_1(G): f\geq 0, \int f d\lambda(x)=1\}$ Prove $\overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^* = \mathfrak{M}(G)$

**My attempt:**

We know ${\widehat{P(G)}} \subset \mathfrak{M}(G)$ therefore, 
$\overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^* \subset \mathfrak{M}(G)$ on the other hand , suppose by contradiction $\mathfrak{M}(G)\not\subset\overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^*$
this shows that there is a $m_0 \in \mathfrak{M}(G)$ such that $m_0 \not\in \overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^*$ so we can find $\phi \in L_\infty (G)$ such that
$$m_0(\phi)>\sup \left\{\hat{f}(\phi): \hat{f} \in \overline{\widehat{P(G)}}^*\right\}$$

I'm stuck here with all the choices I made!!

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: What does the hat mean? It seems that you are trying to reprove Golstine's theorem

Comment: @Dear Adrián González-Pérez , this is Alan L.T. Paterson 
& Amenability 
 "Proposition (0.1)-(iii)"